# Проблема плавного изменения цвета фона DIV с помощью JS

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Есть слой:

```
<div style="background-color:#ff0000; position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px;" onClick="isMove(this)" onMouseOver="change_bg_up(this);" onMouseOut="change_bg_down(this);">Лол</div>
```

Проблема в том, что положение меняется плавно, а цвет меняется **очень** резко.

Вот код скрипта:

Меняем положение *(работает отлично):*

```
function isMove(element) {

   for(t=0;t<100;t++){
      setTimeout(function() {actMove(element)}, t*10);
   }

};

function actMove(element) {
   element.style.left=parseInt(element.style.left)+1+'px';
   element.style.top=parseInt(element.style.top)+2+'px';
}
```

Меняем фон слоя *(работает неправильно):*

```
var hexNum=new Array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F');

function toHex(num) {
  if (num<0) return "00";
  else if (num>255) return "FF";
  else return ""+hexNum[Math.floor(num/16)]+hexNum[num%16];
 }

 function newBgcolor(element,red,green,blue) {
  var hexRed= toHex(red);
  var hexGreen= toHex(green);
  var hexBlue= toHex(blue);
  element.style['background']="#"+hexRed+hexGreen+hexBlue;
 }

 function change_bg_up(element) {
   for(r=0;r<256;r++){
      setTimeout(function() {newBgcolor(element,255,r,r)},r*10);
   }
 }

 function change_bg_down(element) {
   for(r=0;r<256;r++){
      setTimeout(function() {newBgcolor(element,255,255-r,255-r)},r*10);
   }
 }
```

Такое впечатление, что он неправильно преобразует числа цвета (*сам скрипт рабочий - в другом проекте всё плавно*).

**Как исправить проблему?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут ошибка:

```
 function change_bg_up(element) {
   for(r=0;r<256;r++){
    (function(){
      var p = r;
      setTimeout(function() {newBgcolor(element,255,p,p)},p*10);
      })();
   }
 }

 function change_bg_down(element) {
   for(r=0;r<256;r++){
    (function(){
      var p = r;
      setTimeout(function() {newBgcolor(element,255,255-p,255-p)},p*10);
      })();
   }
 }
```

Comment: Сам точно не знаю почему так, но походу происходит так:
все циклы в javascript являются блокирующими, пока работает скрипт, он просто создаёт много запусков функции в которые передаёт переменную r. На момент окончания работы цикла мы имеем 256 фунций завязаных на переменную r, но к этому моменту r = 255, потэтому нужно создавать пространства имён и назначать r на другую внутреннюю переменную, у меня - p

Comment: премного благодарен, действительно заработало :)
не додумался до такого варианта.

P.S. как сложно жить))

Comment: я и сам не знал, пока не прочёл книгу Джона Рейсига